# Meet me at the fence

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Your trickster friend asked you to meet him at... *the fence*:

[image: the wall]

He also gave you this: `husztyrotzltnlm-uipi.ltpnstcah-g:/o/eeS/mrE`

You are wary of this practical joker, but you figure it can't hurt to just see what he's trying to say, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's trying to say

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ (yes, I'm serious)

because

> Apply [railfence cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher) with 7 rails (number of brick rows stacked in the image) to `husztyrotzltnlm-uipi.ltpnstcah-g:/o/eeS/mrE`, you get `https://tinyurl.com/almost-there-puzzlingSE` -> which redirects to this wonderful youtube video

Comment: Did I get you? :P

Comment: Congrats on 1k btw!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Yes, yes you did :) Thanks!